# Visual Studio Extension: Custom Quick Action

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2017

I need to generate a custom type of wrapper class from any existing one. An existing C# application is doing this very well, but its usage is quite annoying as it involves opening the application with the right file path, moving the generated file to the target location, modify the namespace and adding it to the Visual Studio solution.

I know that there might be other solutions, but I decided that I want an extension to do this (also for educational purpose). Target IDE is Visual Studio 2017 and it does not need to be backwards compatible.

For the usability it would be best to somehow extend the quick action menu when a class name is focused. There should be a possibility to do it, but I failed to find any resources on it.

Comment: What do you mean by "generate a custom type of wrapper class" and what does this have to do with VS Extensions? Please explain what your "existing C# application" does - you haven't provided much background exposition.

Comment: Actually the code generation is not the problem, but how to extend the quick action menu. I tried to specify my question, to make that clearer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, for everyone that struggled like me:

My problem was that I searched for "quick action" instead of "light bulb". So after browsing the msdn documentation on extensibility, I finally found what I was looking for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-displaying-light-bulb-suggestions?view=vs-2022

Comment: Can't seem to edit, but https://web.archive.org/web/20170623141028/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn903708.aspx is the archive link as the one in the answer is dead.

Comment: @Joald Thanks for notifying me about the dead link. I've updated the link with the current wiki page.